# Error ejecutar proyecto ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, asp.net-core

Como saben MS lanzó la versión de visual studio para OSX, mi programa corre en development, pero al momento de intentar ejecutar el proyecto desde la terminal sin VS aparece el siguiente error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1111,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/Users/devOps92/Projects/SampleAPI/SampleAPI/SampleAPI.csproj]

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar a solucionar el problema o me den una idea de como solucionarlo.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: a qué framework está apuntando tu app ?

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que dice el error pareciera que tu proyecto usa el full framework o tiene alguna dependencia de este tipo. En el mensaje se lee: ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" y eso es el full framework y sólo funciona en windows.

Para que sea cross platform y funcione en mac y linux tenés que usar .net core, o sea tu "target framework" tiene que ser net core app 1.x o net standard 1.x. Y no .net framework 4.6.2.

Como primera medida fijate en las propiedades de tu/s proyecto/s, en el tab de aplicación, para ver a qué framework apunta/n.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a verificar y te doy el feedback.